# Closing speed and time needed for light to reach moving object

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics

I've come across this kind of problems where I need to find a time interval for light rays to reach a moving observer.

Suppose Bob is travelling towards a mirror at a speed $v$ relative to the mirror. When he is at a distance $d$ from the mirror (as measured by him), he shone a light towards the mirror. The question asks for the time interval the light needed to travel to the mirror and back to Bob (as measured by Bob).

When the light is shone, the mirror is at $x=d$. We need to find the time interval needed for light to reach the mirror.

The light hits the mirror when the light and the mirror is at the same position, thus: $d-v\cdot\Delta t_1=c\cdot \Delta t_1$

Solving this equation, we got: $\Delta t_1=\frac{d}{c+v}$

Then we need to find the time interval light needed to travel back to Bob. The moment light reaches the mirror Bob is at distance $d'=c\cdot\Delta t_1$ away from the light.

Thus it needs $\Delta t_2=\frac{c\cdot \Delta t_1}{c} = \Delta t_1$

Which means the total travel time is: $2\cdot \Delta t_1 = \frac{2d}{c+v}$

This approach seems overly complicated. I've seen my textbook solve these problems rather simply by what seems to be called a *closing speed* which is the rate of change of distance between objects. So, how exactly do we apply closing speed to these problems, and why does it works?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not complicated at all, in fact I would suggest you solve any problem like this involving doppler shifts from basics as you did. You will get a hang of it, and if you use closing speed it won't be applicable at all times. This is the best way of solving relative velocity problems, if say both the source mirror observer everyone are moving its confusing what you would call the closing speed then.

Comment: Thanks, I also think my way seems more logical for these problems. Just want to know how that _closing speed_ method also works.